# Converting HR to OR for meta-analysis (or vice versa)

Tags: meta-analysis

I've looked both in SO and others (Borenshtein's) and have yet to find an answer.
I have some studies that provide an adjusted OR estimate, some HR, and then some with adjusted RR. I can subgroup and report them based on treatment effect, but I am also interested in bundling them.
My colleague suggested treating RR as HR and then converting to OR to RR (formula available in the [cochrane handbook](http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_12/image018.gif) - a solution I'm not really satisfied with, since RR != HR, and that also requires me to extrapolate baseline risk from univariate data. In addition I'll end up describing with RR although almost all studies use a different measure.

However I couldn't find an appropriate method/ function for HR -> OR.

Can someone point me in the direction?
[This](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/hazodds) describes converting log-hazard to probability and then back, but going the other way around again I don't have baseline hazard.

Comment: I think you already have there a manageable approach: convert OR to RR using control event rate, and then assume RR are a reasonable approximation of HR. I am not aware of any other sounder approach.

Comment: I thought it was desirable to describe OR. Besides, things get weird when one approximating HR as RR as face value, e.g- getting confidence interval beyond 100% risk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130237/convert-hazards-ratio-to-odds-ratio