# Meta Analysis: how to compare RR, OR, HR

Tags: meta-analysis

I have a 5 study dataset with 2 IRRs, 2 ORs and 1 HR, all with CIs given.  Can I do a log transformation and then conduct a meta analysis. What is a plausible way to conduct meta analysis in this case

Comment: It is hard to compare the three, which is one reason to only use individual subject-level meta analysis where you can recompute whatever index you want.

Comment: You can refer to this earlier post for OR to RR conversion (and viceversa): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131416/converting-adjusted-odds-ratios-to-its-rr-counterpart
HR are roughly an estimator of RR, so you might consider them equivalent
However, if follow-up time varies, probably the most robust approach is to compute IRR