# Approximating OR with RRR in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, relative-risk

Similarly as in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/how-to-conduct-a-meta-analysis-on-studies-that-report-results-variously-as-odds), I'm working with meta-analysis of studies reporting ORs of an event.

I have [one study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2820660/) where I'm not sure if it should be excluded.

The frequencies of the outcome are: 
No outcome: 85%
Outcome 1: 6%
Outcome 2: 9%

Authors use 'multivariate multinomial logistic' regression using this outcome and report adjusted effects as RRR. This estimates refer to continuous variable coded 1 to 4 and range from 1.14 to 2.97 in different models and would be the estimated pooled to meta-analysis.

I know that [in case of rare events (sometimes quoted as <10% incidence)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00038-008-7068-3), RRs approximate ORs.. My question is – would that hold for multinomial model? And is 9% + 6% still rare? Effectively - can these RRRs be use as approximation of ORs?

Comment: Is there some reason, why one cannot calculate the odds ratio from the reports of the study (e.g. outcome vs. no outcome)?

Answer (score 0):

Pointers from Roberto Gutierrez on [this answer on Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2005-04/msg00678.html)and the fact that the authors used multinomial model slowly make me believe that this study will be excluded.