# Examples of meta-analyses where individual associatons are reported as odds ratios, risk ratios, or hazard ratios

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, hazard, relative-risk

I am analyzing data from 17 studies (25 data points) with mixed measures of association (OR, RR, HR). Most associations are less than 2.0, with four  from 2.0 to 3.1. Only one is less than 1.0 (not significant).

My options are fairly limited. Will consider doing stratified meta-analysis.

Are there some examples where the investigators did the meta-analysis using mixed-type measures of association?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this has already been asked and answered here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/how-to-conduct-a-meta-analysis-on-studies-that-report-results-variously-as-odds?rq=1

Comment: I saw that question and answer, and will probably end up taking one or more of those approaches. But does anyone know of a publication where OR, RR, HR were used and how it was justified? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I reccommend is to convert odds ratios into relative risks using the control group event rate as baseline, and then pool relative risks and hazard ratios together.

You may stratify the analysis to show consistency distinguishing relative risks and hazard ratios, though.